# Having issue designing database for such cases

Tags: php, mysql

I have a employee table and in this we store his employee id and project and account name to which he belongs. When he changes his account after few months, it is becoming to track him in both accounts as we modify the account name in his record. 
How do we handle such situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, one should read about [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and start using it in practice.

Relational databases are about relations. When you store data in different columns of the same table, it is assumed that the data in columns is in one-to-one relation to the whole row. When you feel that the relation is not one-to-one, it is usually time to think of data decomposition and reorganization the principles of which are tightly bound to the mentioned Database Normalization.